# Min cost max flow variant

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization

Let $$ be the set of customers and let $_⊆$ be the set of items from which customer $∈$ wants to buy only one, where $$ are the items. Denote $(,)≥0$ as the price customer $$ is willing to pay for item $$. Assume $||=||=.$

The question is to find a polynomial time algorithm which maximizes the total revenue independent of the number of customers that actually get an item.

To do this, I created a bipartite graph $I$ and $J$ with source $s$ and sink $t$.
$$
(s,i), i \in I \\
(j,t), j \in J
$$
with capacity $1$ and cost $0$. The cost function we make
$$
w^*(i, j) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{w(i,j)} & w(i,j) \neq 0 \\ 0 &otherwise\end{cases}.
$$

where edge $(i,j)$ has capacity 1 if $j \in J_i$.
Now, we solve this problem using a min cost max flow algorithm. However, there can be scenario's where a higher flow is selected with a lower cost (and hence lower revenue) where a lower flow with a higher cost should have been selected.

How do I use the min-cost max flow algorithm to select the highest cost unrelated to the amount of flow?

Comment: This sounds like an assignment problem, if I understand it right.  Can't you just set the weights to $-w(i,j)$?

Comment: It is indeed an assignment problem. The min cost max flow algorithms require the cost function to be nonnegative. Do you have a suggestion on how we can solve this problem?

Comment: I seem to recall that you can use the Hungarian algorithm by just negating the costs, but it's been quite some time since I looked at it.  In any event, I feel certain that the Hungarian algorithm can be used either for minimization or maximization, though the adjustment might be different.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into the Hungarian algorithm. Isn't that similar to a primal dual algorithm? Can we maybe use the primal-dual algorithm for maximum cost flows? I have tried that, but haven't found a solution either

Comment: http://www.cse.ust.hk/~golin/COMP572/Notes/Matching.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it so that everyone is willing to buy every item (but possibly only willing to pay a price of $0$ for it) and you ensure that the maximum flow is $n$.

Your cost function doesn't order $w(i,j)=0$ correctly, so instead use $w^*(i,j) = -w(i,j)$.

At this point, a min-cost max flow will maximize the total revenue. (Ignore edges with $w(i,j)=0$ in the solution, if you like; it won't change the answer.)

This can also be solved as an assignment problem, of course, but this is the min-cost max-flow approach.